# Why would a Google Protocol buffers message not bind automagically in a Spring MVC controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, protocol-buffers

I have a standard form controller to update a google protocol buffers message object that gets persisted. For the form I add the Message.Builder to the ModelMap so that I have access to the setter message. However, the values I change in the form are not automatically bound to the Builder object. I can not figure out why that doesn't work... I do have the message in the @SessionAttributes. Below is a summerized version of my implementation.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String setup(ModelMap modelMap) {
   Message.Builder builder = Message.Builder.newBuilder(serviceLayer.getMessage(someId));
   modelMap.addAttribute("message", builder);
   return "form";
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String process(@ModelAttribute("message") Message message) {
   serviceLayer.saveMessage(message.build());
   return "done";
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the `@SessionAttributes` also?

Comment: @SessionAttributes("message"). I can set a value in my setup method and see it in my debuger on the process method. So I know the message is passed through the session correctly.

Comment: Also in my form I use the spring form taglib. <form:form modelattribute="message">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Messages embedded the getter methods only return an immutable object even from the Builder. Instead I had to reconstruct the Message from bottom up using the HttpServletRequest.